# Google Guice Assisted Inject object is null

Tags: java, guice

I need to create objects with user defined data at runtime.TO do that i have used 
google guice assisted inject.But when i run my test it throws `null` pointer exception.Please let me know where i made the mistake.

**IArtifacts Interface**

```
public interface IArtifacts {

    MavenMetaDataXMLDTO getArtifactsVersions();
}
```

**ArtifactsService.java**

```
public class ArtifactsService implements IArtifacts {

    private ProductProfile productProfile;

    @Inject
    public ArtifactsService(@Assisted ProductProfile productProfile){
        System.out.println(productProfile.getArtifactManagementURL());
        this.productProfile=productProfile;
    }

    @Override
    public MavenMetaDataXMLDTO getArtifactsVersions() {

        System.out.println(productProfile.getArtifactManagementURL());
        return null;
    }
}
```

**ArtifactsFactory Interface**

```
public interface ArtifactsFactory {

    IArtifacts create(ProductProfile productProfile);
}
```

**Module Class**

```
@Override
    protected void configure() {
    install(new FactoryModuleBuilder().implement(IArtifacts.class,ArtifactsService.class).build(ArtifactsFactory.class));
}
```

**TestArtifacts.java**

```
public class TestArtifacts {

    @Inject // this obj is null
    private ArtifactsFactory artifactsFactory;

    private  IArtifacts s;

    public TestArtifacts(){

    }

    public void getdata(){
        //Pass custom data to factory
        this.s=artifactsFactory.create(Products.QA.get());
        System.out.println(s.getArtifactsVersions());
    }


}
```

**REST ENDPOINT**

```
    @GET
    @Path("/test")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public String getartifacts(){
      new TestArtifacts().getdata();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix it adding following code snippet to below TestArtifacts.java class

**TestArtifacts.java**

```
 private Injector injector=Guice.createInjector(new MYModule());//where implemented configuration

    @Inject
    private ArtifactsFactory artifactsFactory=injector.getInstance(ArtifactsFactory.class);
```

Answer (score 1):

you created an Instance of the class TestArtifacts on your own in your Rest Endpoint class but all of your classes need to be created by the Guice Framework and not by you.

So how should the Guice Framework inject something into your class when you create them with new? You also need to inject the class TestArtifacts into your Rest Endpoint and your Rest Endpoint has to be created by Guice too.

Update:

Maybe this link will help you

https://sites.google.com/a/athaydes.com/renato-athaydes/posts/jersey_guice_rest_api

Comment: thanks for quick reply.do you have any samples to refer.